# Set of unstable initial conditions

Tags: complex-systems

Suppose I have some equations of motion for the variables $x(t),y(t)$
\begin{align}
0&=\ddot x + b(t) \dot x + V_x(x,y)\,,\\
0&=\ddot y + b(t) \dot y + V_y(x,y)\,,
\end{align}
where the potential $V$ has a saddle point at, say $x = y = 0$. Is there an efficient formalism to compute set of initial conditions $x(0),y(0),\dot x(0),\dot y(0)$ such that $x(\infty) = y(\infty) = \dot x(\infty) = \dot y(\infty) = 0$? Or, is there a physical way to pose this problem that makes the solution intuitive? Numerically this problem is not hard, but I think there should be a nice way to phrase the problem that makes the solution better motivated than "pure numerics."

Comment: Not the Potential, but the partial derivatives of the potential